# Maximization of trig function

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Is there anyway I can find 
$$
\underset{\phi ~\in~ [0, 2\pi)}{\arg \max}~~~ \cos^2(\phi - \phi_L - \tilde{\phi}/2)\cos^2\left(k [\cos(\phi - \phi_s) - \cos(\phi_L - \phi_s)]\right)\cos^2(\tilde{\phi}/ 2)
+ ~{\sin^2(\phi - \phi_L - \tilde{\phi}/2)}\sin^2\left(k [\cos(\phi - \phi_s) - \cos(\phi_L - \phi_s)]\right)\sin^2(\tilde{\phi}/ 2)
?
$$
I have tried the first derivative method and ran into a case of $\phi$ and a trig function of $\phi$.

Any geometrical interpretation of the above would be very helpful.

NB: Just a reminder, I am only interested in maximizing with respect to $\phi$.

Comment: I understand that trig function of trig function (e.g. $\cos(\sin(\phi))$) can be expressed in terms of Bessel function of the first kind. Any suggestion on how that could apply here?